# SQL Script cursor and loop

Tags: sql, scripting

Basically I have to do a script as a project. The script needs to return through cursor and loop the names of employees (first and last name) from example table ''Employees'', with First_name value is no less than 4 symbols.

It is suggested that we should use function LENGTH.

Comment: What have you tried?  What issues did you encounter?  What is your specific question?  Or are you asking us to do ***all*** your homework for you?  *(If so, at least have the courtesy to post the exact question and all the associated material?)*.

Comment: What happens if you google your question?

Answer (score 1):

```
  DECLARE
  FNAME EMPLOYEE.FIRSTNAME%TYPE,
   LNAME EMPLOYEE.LASTNAME%TYPE,
   CURSOR C1 IS 
   SELECT FIRSTNAME,LASTNAME
   FROM EMPLOYEES 
   WHERE LENGTH(FIRSTNAME)<4;
  BEGIN
  OPEN C1;
  LOOP
  FETCH C1.FIRSTNAME,C1.LASTNAME INTO 
  F_NAME,L_NAME ;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(FNAME||'|'||LNAME);
  EXIT WHEN C1%NOTFOUND;
 END LOOP;
  CLOSE C1;
 END;
```

I hope the database is oracle. Can work around with the above query

Comment: but the firstname vlaue is no less than 4 symbols it should be >=4

Comment: I thought the OP is trying to say a number less than 4 so wrote likewise :)

Comment: Thank you Himanshu! That’s what i was looking for. My uni teacher is a bit crappy and Doesn’t explain things very well